# Can anyone please help me identify this plant?

Tags: botany, species-identification

Please help me identify this plant. My aunt had one but it died due to the drought in California. She wants to get a new one but she doesn't know what it's called. The leaves are around two inches and it is seedless, though I'm not sure if it's native in California. Suggestions are welcomed!

[image: a plant branch]

Comment: Welcome to Biology. Species identification questions are warmly welcomed, but without knowing more details it is impossible to identify this plant. Important things to mention are: 1) Was this an indoor or outdoor plant 2) Was it a native or not 3) Where do you live 4) Did it flower, and if yes, what did the flowers look like 4) How big was it 5) How old was it 6) What was the size of the leaves? ...etc.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but please answer all 5 questions that AliceD asked.

Comment: Not sure but looks like *Acacia auriculiformis* (Mimosaceae) and *Eucalyptus sp* (Myrtaceae) , both big trees. Provide image of  fresh/ pressed leaves, and a much better description.